# Include relationship when querying node using Prisma generated wrapper

Tags: graphql, prisma, plumatic-schema, prisma-graphql

I am following the [GraphQL Prisma Typescript](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-prisma-typescript) example provided by Prisma and created a simple data model, generated the code for the Prisma client and resolvers, etc.

My data model includes the following nodes:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  displayName: String!
}

type SystemUserLogin {
  id: ID! @unique
  username: String! @unique
  passwordEnvironmentVariable: String!
  user: User!
}
```

I've seeded with a system user and user.

```
mutation {
  systemUserLogin: createSystemUserLogin({
    data: {
      username: "SYSTEM",
      passwordEnvironmentVariable: "SYSTEM_PASSWORD",
      user: {
        create: {
          displayName: "System User"
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I've created a sample mutation `login`:

```
login: async (_parent, { username, password }, ctx) => {
    let user
    const systemUser = await ctx.db.systemUserLogin({ username })
    const valid = systemUser && systemUser.passwordEnvironmentVariable && process.env[systemUser.passwordEnvironmentVariable] &&(process.env[systemUser.passwordEnvironmentVariable] === password)

    if (valid) {
      user = systemUser.user // this is always undefined!
    }

    if (!valid || !user) {
      throw new Error('Invalid Credentials')
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET)

    return {
      token,
      user: ctx.db.user({ id: user.id }),
    }
  },
```

But no matter what I do, `systemUser.user` is ALWAYS undefined!

This makes sense - how would the client wrapper know how "deep" to recurse into the graph without me telling it?

But how can I tell it that I want to include the `User` relationship?

### Edit: I tried the suggestion below to use `prisma-client`.

But none of my resolvers ever seem to get called...

```
export const SystemUserLogin: SystemUserLoginResolvers.Type<TypeMap> = {
  id: parent => parent.id,
  user: (parent, args, ctx: any) => {
    console.log('resolving')
    return ctx.db.systemUserLogin({id: parent.id}).user()
  },
  environmentVariable: parent => parent.environmentVariable,
  systemUsername: parent => parent.systemUsername,
  createdAt: parent => parent.createdAt,
  updatedAt: parent => parent.updatedAt
};
```

And...

```
  let identity: UserParent;

  const systemUserLogins = await context.db.systemUserLogins({
    where: {
      systemUsername: user,
    }
  });
  const systemUserLogin = (systemUserLogins) ? systemUserLogins[0] : null ;

  if (systemUserLogin && systemUserLogin.environmentVariable && process.env[systemUserLogin.environmentVariable] && process.env[systemUserLogin.environmentVariable] === password) {
    console.log('should login!')

    identity = systemUserLogin.user; // still null
  }
```

### Edit 2: Here is the repository

https://github.com/jshin47/annotorious/tree/master/server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently two ways to solve this problem:

- Using the **Prisma client** as OP does at the moment
- Using **Prisma bindings** as was suggested by @User97 in the accepted answer

You can learn more about the difference between Prisma client and Prisma bindings in [this](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/help-understanding-prisma-clients-value-proposition/4394/17) forum post.

As OP is currently using Prisma client, I'll use it for this answer as well!

Let's take a look at a statement OP made in the question:

> This makes sense - how would the client wrapper know how "deep" to recurse into the graph without me telling it?

OP stated correctly that the Prisma client can't know how to deep to go into the graph and what relationships to fetch. In fact, unless *explicitly* told otherwise (e.g. using the [`$fragment` API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#using-fragments-for-fine-grained-data-access)), the client will never fetch any relationships and will always only fetch the scalar values. From the [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2):

> Whenever a model is queried using the Prisma client, all scalar fields of that model are fetched. This is true no matter if a single object or a list of objects is queried.

So, how to properly resolve this situation? In fact, the solution is *not* to make changes to the way how the Prisma client is used, but to implement an additional GraphQL resolver function!

The point about resolvers is that they're fetching the data for  *specific* fields in your schema. In OP's case, there currently is no resolver that would "resolve" the `user` relation that's defined on the `SystemUserLogin` type:

```
type SystemUserLogin {
  id: ID! @unique
  username: String! @unique
  passwordEnvironmentVariable: String!
  user: User! # GraphQL doesn't know how to resolve this
}
```

To resolve this situation, you need to implement a dedicated "type resolver" for it like so:

```
const resolvers = {
  SystemUserLogin: {
    user(parent, args, ctx) {
      return ctx.db.systemUserLogin({id: parent.id}).user()
    }
  } 
}
```

Full disclosure: I work at Prisma and we're working on adding better documentation and resources for that use case. Also check out [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/master/node-graphql) example where explicit resolvers for the `author` and `posts` relation fields are required for the same reason.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**: We have also added a slightly more thorough explanation in the Prisma tutorial about [Common resolver patterns](https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-common-resolver-patterns-ct08/#scenario:-implementing-relations-with-prisma-client).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was wondering what the difference was! I have found the documentation to be wanting, so this really helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion using `prisma-client` and it seems like my resolver is never actually called, so I am still unable to get it to work with `prisma-client`

Comment: Hmm this is strange! Did you double check that the resolvers are actually passed to your GraphQL server? Normally when a query is resolved, the resolvers for _all_ fields inside the query should be called! So if you're sending a query that uses the `user` of `SystemUserLogin` the `user` resolver should get called. If no, there might be an issue somewhere else!

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue in the meantime @tacos_tacos_tacos? Is the resolver still not called?

Comment: The resolver is still not called... tonight when I get home I will copy and paste the code from the entry point on down... Any ideas?

Comment: Do you maybe have a link to a GitHub repo so I can reproduce the issue? Currently it's difficult for me to tell where the error is since my understanding is that the resolver _should_ be called. So I believe the point we need to investigate is why it is not called.

Comment: any idea about what's going wrong with my example? I provided a link to repo

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter of prisma binding functions accept GraphQL query string. Changing following line from

```
const systemUser = await ctx.db.query.systemUserLogin({ username })
```

to

```
const systemUser = await ctx.db.query.systemUserLogin({ username }, `{id username user {id displayName}}`)
```

will give you the data of user.

Prisma binding will return only direct properties of model in case second parameter is not passed to it.

Comment: I was really hoping this sort of thing would work, but I tried and it doesn't, and the method's interface suggests that it only accepts one parameter anyway: `systemUserLogin: (where: SystemUserLoginWhereUniqueInput) => SystemUserLogin;`

Comment: And `ctx.db.query` is `undefined`

Comment: Are you setting `db` in context while initialising your server?

Comment: Yes, but I was importing the wrong `Prisma`, I guess... `import {Prisma} from "./generated/prisma";` works, `import {Prisma} from "./generated/prisma-client";` doesnt

Comment: There are two ways to query data from Prisma. You can either use `prisma-binding` or `prisma-client`. My answer uses `prisma-binding`. For `prisma-client`, this is how relationships are queried: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#relations

Comment: Sorry for the confusion around Prisma client and Prisma bindings. Hope my answer helps 